# Run time error '438'-Only Sometimes

Tags: vba, excel, runtime-error

I keep getting this error message but only the first time I run my vba code. If I run it again after the error, it works.
This code is edited according to what I understood from the first answer
Any help would be very much appreciated.

---

**New Code**

```
Sheets("Sheet1").Copy
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Add

'this creates the "Save as". Change sheets as to your sheet. The new
'workbook is now the active one
strFileName = "C:\Users\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Name & ".xls"
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("B4").Value & Range("E6").Value & " vs " _
& Range("E7").Value & " - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
wb.Close
```

---

**Original Code in question:**

```
strFileName = "C:\Users\" & Sheets("Sheet1").Name & ".xls"
If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=Range("B4").Value & Range("E6").Value & " vs " _
& Range("E7").Value & " - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
ActiveWorkbook.Close0
```

Comment: Which line errors? Is there a space before the 0 in the last line?

Comment: This line `If strFileName = "False" Then Exit Sub` can never be true???

Comment: What are you trying to do with this? `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Add`?  The `Sheet` object doesn't have an `Add` method. That's a 438 error. To create a new workbook at runtime, it's simply: `Set wb = Workbooks.Add`

Comment: Also, do `wb.SaveAs ...` instead of `ActiveWorkbook`.

Comment: I am trying to get the new workbook to contain sheet 1

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: @theudster I'm glad we can help. I would like to also explain, that this site is meant as to be a knowledge repository. If you need additional help, please ask a new question, instead of further editing this one. If you attach a link to the new question in a comment on my answer; I'll take a look at it and see if I can help. (Also, it's good etiquette on this site, to mark an answer as accepted, if it solved your original question.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no `.Close0` for workbook objects.

This line:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close0
```

should be:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

---

Notes:

- You have the option to specify if you wish to save changes with `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True` or `ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=False`
- If you have more than one workbook open at a time, using `ActiveWorkbook.Close` may close a different workbook then expected. It is usually better to use one of the following:

  1. `ThisWorkbook.Close` -- If the workbook being closed is the one holding the code
  2. `Workbooks("Name").Close` -- If you don't have the workbook as a variable **AND** the workbook being closed is not the one with the code. However, this method is discouraged, as it involves hard-coding the workbook name into the code. This could cause the code to break if the name gets changed.
  3. `wbk.Close` -- Where `wbk` is a workbook object referencing/holding the workbook you wish to close

---

- If the Workbook is pre-existing, it can be set to a variable like:

  ---

this

```
Dim wkb as Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks("Name")
```

or

```
Dim wkb as Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Open("FileName")
```

---

- If the workbook has been newly created, it can be set to a variable like:

  ---

this

```
Dim wkb as Workbook
Set wkb = Workbooks.Add
```

or

```
' Although the previous method is preferred
Dim wkb as Workbook
Workbooks.Add
Set wkb = ActiveWorkbook
```

---

**Edit:**

Realized that you may have been attempting to use `ActiveWorkbook.Close 0` to indicate `True/False` for `SaveChanges`, but it would probably be better to use `True/False` instead of `-1,0,1`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, Im trying to close a different workbook which was generated by by this code. Im just not sure what to set the wbk as in order to make sure it references to this new workbook.

Comment: @theudster I edited my answer to include some examples.

Comment: thanks so much  for your help. Im quit new to this and this may be a noob question, but I edited my question to reflect the changes you suggested and still keep getting errors. Help would be appreciated .

Comment: @theudster Is the error still the `438` error? If so, where is it in the updated code? If not, you should probably create a new question; as this seems like a new problem. Also, if you are trying to do as @David Zemens surmises -- create a new workbook from an existing sheet -- it would be helpful to have that additional explanation (or corrected explanation) in the new question.

Answer (score 0):

What are you trying to do with this? `Set wb = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Add`?  The `Sheet` object doesn't have an `Add` method. That's a 438 error.

To create a new workbook at runtime, you can use the `Workbooks.Add` method

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
```

To create a new workbook *from an existing worksheet*, as it seems maybe you're trying to do, it's one of few times where it's OK to use `ActiveWorkbook`:

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
ws.Copy   ' If Destination isn't specified, this creates a new workbook
Dim wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' The newly created workbook is Active now

strFileName = "C:\Users\" & ws.Name & ".xls" '<~~ this variable is never used, it doesn't do anything. You may want to remove it to avoid ambiguity.

wb.SaveAs Filename:=Range("B4").Value & Range("E6").Value & " vs " _
& Range("E7").Value & " - " & Format(Date, "dd-mm-yyyy")
wb.Close
```

**NOTE**: unless the values that you're using to derive the `Filename` exist on Sheet 1, this may cause an error or save as some other, unexpected filename. It is recommended that you always *fully qualify* range objects, otherwise Excel default assumes they are on whatever worksheet is Active at runtime.

Comment: Hi, thanks but this seems to close the current excel workbook as well and also stops other parts of my code from working.

Comment: Try `Set wb = Workbooks(Workbooks.Count)` . That *should* ensure it's the newly created workbook. Otherwise, you need to clarify what the problem is, and perhaps learn a little bit of debugging (see [here](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx)) via trial and error :)

Comment: The code as given above closes the newly-created workbook. is that not what you want? If you don't want to close it, then just omit the `wb.Close` statement. If you want to close a *different* workbook, then you'll need to specify which.